# Why do i get the error "malloc(): corrupted top size"?

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to implement stack using dynamic arrays:

```cpp
class stackArray{
public:
    stackArray(){mainArr = new int[arrSize];}

    void push(int data){
        if(curr > arrSize){
            int *newArr = new int[arrSize*2];
            for(int i = 0 ; i < arrSize; ++i){
                newArr[i] = mainArr[i];
            }
            arrSize *= 2;
            delete []mainArr;
            mainArr = newArr;
        }
            mainArr[++curr] = data;
    }
    void print(){ // debug
        for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i){
            std::cout << mainArr[i];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

private:
    int *mainArr;
    int curr = -1;
    int arrSize = 10;
};
```

and for some reason, whenever `curr > arrSize` is true and allocate a new memory called `newArr` it produces `malloc(): corrupted top size`. I'm still new in dynamic memory and I don't understand this error. can anybody explain it and how to solve this?

Comment: Tip: Use stuff like `std::copy` instead of this.

Comment: Step through in a debugger to find out more.

Comment: You double the size of the array, but don't change `arrsize` That's gonna bite sooner or later.

Comment: Do you update `arrSize` when resizing?

Comment: oh yeah i forgot about updating the `arrSize`. still, the error still in there.

Comment: Yup the error will still be there. Remember that arrays in C++ are origin zero. Valid between 0 and `arrSize` -1.

Comment: `if(curr > arrSize)` ==> `if(curr == arrSize)`

Comment: ahhh i see, so that's what it is haha i've solved it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially the data member `curr` is equal tp `-1`.

Now for simplicity let's assume that the initial value of the data member `arrSize` is equal to `1`. That is the constructor dynamically allocated an array with one element.

So as `curr` is not greater than `arrSize` you are setting `mainArr[0]` within the function `push`.  Now `curr` is equal to `0`

```
mainArr[++curr] = data;
```

And again `curr` is not greater than `arrSize`. So in a next call of push you are trying to overwrite memory that does not belong to the dynamically allocated array that is you are trying to access memory using the expression `mainArr[1]`.

You need to update correctly the if statement within the function. For example

```
if( !( curr + 1 < arrSize ) ){
```

Pay attention to that the function `print` in general is not correct because you are not initializing all elements of a newly allocated dynamically array.

```
void print(){ // debug
    for(int i = 0; i < arrSize; ++i){
        std::cout << mainArr[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I see, Thanks for the explanation. can you give me an explanation on why "malloc(): corrupted top size" happen?

Comment: @0_NULL You are overwriting memory that results in undefined behavior.

Comment: i'm really sorry but i don't understand what you mean by "overwriting memory" how does this happen?

Comment: @0_NULL As I wrote you are trying to access a memory that was not allocated.